# Stop sorting Android Notifications

Tags: android, notifications

I need update notification content. How can I do this?

I do this in Thread:

```
notificationManager.notify(new Integer(id), notification);
```

My Notification body:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SingleNewsActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("id", id);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("title", title);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("text", text);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, activity, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    activity++;

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_bitcoin_notification);
    builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
    builder.setTicker(bar);
    builder.setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setContentText(text);
    builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    if(!silent){
        builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    }
    builder.setVibrate(null);


    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(new Integer(id), notification);
```

And setup unique static ID for 3 notifications, but in `Thread`, when I use `notify`, Notifications in Android change positions.

How can I disable sorting and do static position for my notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android orders notifications by priority and then by time. If you want to keep your notifications ordered relative to each other, either give them different priorities, or make sure the times stay in that order. Neither of those seem like great options, though...

It's generally discouraged for an app to have multiple notifications at the same time. Perhaps you should look for a way to consolidate them into one instead.

Comment: I'll give you a scenario, I have a downloader, I downloaded 3 items, I wanted to see in notification the percentage of each, each time each item changes their percentage, it hoist itself up. Another example is multiple timers. Any ideas how to develop multiple notifications given this situation? I see Utorrent app, Opera browser download does this. Whenever I have multiple downloads, it shows 2 items in notification and they stay in position when gets updated.

Answer (score 2):

If you use "setWhen" in your notification's builder it does the trick

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( context, "channel_name_here" );
builder.setContentTitle( "My notification" );
builder.setWhen( long uniqueTimeForEveryRequest );
NotificationManagerCompat.from( context ).notify( yourUniqueId, builder.build() );
```

You can see more info about "setWhen" in android docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setWhen(long)